# Use Cauchy integral formula to determine an integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I am trying to use CIF to solve $$\int_\gamma (z^2-4)^{-1} dz$$ where $\gamma$ is the unit circle traversed once in the positive direction.

If I let $f(z) = z^2-4$, then $f$ is not analytic at $\pm2$. However, neither of these points lie within $\gamma$. Thus, I am not sure how to continue this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(z^2 - 4)^{-1}$ is holomorphic within the unit disk. Thus the integral is $0$ by Goursat's theorem.

Comment: Just curious, are you calling Cauchy–Goursat theorem Goursat's theorem instead of Cauchy's theorem for some special reasons? :)

Comment: @frank000 My textbook calls it Goursat's theorem. I prefer "Goursat's theorem" since there are so many things named after Cauchy.